# jQuery event when the bottom of the overflow is reached?

Tags: jquery, css, overflow

I am using the css overflow property on a web page with a list of products. I have found that with mobile devices when browsing the web page there is no scroll bar, I would like to add a div or something to tell the user to keep scrolling but also for the div to disappear when the bottom of the overflow is reached. jQuery doesn't seem to understand the overflow, so nothing happens. When no overflow is used the jQuery works fine, Here is the code I found:

```
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(window).scroll(function() {
                if ($(".overflow").height() <= ($(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop())) {
                    alert('Bottom reached!');
                }
            });
        });    
    </script>
```

I am also open to other suggestions / ways of doing this, thank you

Comment: I also don't understand the overflow ;-) The way you wrote it you are checking a dom element with the class "overflow".

Comment: So, here is the overflow `<div class="content" style="padding : 4px; width : 732px; height : 600px; overflow : auto; ">Content here</div>` this sets a height of 600px, if there is more content than 600px's worth then the div will stay the same size but add a scroll bar and the user navigates down or up in the overflow div.